# RegEx for text with double quotes in Calabash

Tags: ios, ruby, regex, cucumber, calabash

I have a scenario in auth.feature file:

```
Scenario: Authorize
Given I am on the Main View
When I touch the "ServiceButton" button
```

and a step for touch in auth_steps.rb file:

```
When(/^I touch the "([^\"]*)" button$/) do |button|
    touch("button marked:'#{button}'")
    sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end
```

When I try to use it, I have an error:

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

When(/^I touch the “ServiceButton” button$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

I used several regex, but nothing is working. The only solution I found is

```
When(/^I touch the (.*) button$/) do |button|
```

but in this case, I need to write the button name without quotes, and this is not what I want.

This is what I use: Xamarin, iPhone SDK 6.1, calabash-iOs. To test my app with calabash, I launch app through Xamarin and then type in console `cucumber NO_LAUNCH=1`.

I will be very grateful if someone could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: use normal double-quotes instead of Unicode “

Comment: What does 'normal double-quotes' means?)

Comment: normal are those which exists in ASCII table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your step definition into:

```
When(/^I touch the “([^\"]*)“ button$/) do |button|
    touch("button marked:'#{button}'")
    sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end
```